# Angular Material - how to make dynamic hash reference for mat-menus

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am displaying a list of mat-chip from an array and would like to add a menu to each one but I am not sure how to reference the mat-menu to be triggered. The mat-chip display looks like this:

```
<mat-chip *ngFor="let user of users"> {{ user }} </mat-chip>
```

And elsewhere I am using mat-menu like this:

```
<mat-chip[matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"> click for menu </mat-chip>
<mat-menu #menu>
    <button (click)="actionOne()" mat-menu-item> one </button>
    <button (click)="actionTwo()" mat-menu-item> two </button>
</mat-menu>
```

I want to combine these to look something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
    <mat-chip[matMenuTriggerFor]="menu+user"> click {{ user }} menu </mat-chip>
    <mat-menu #menu{{user}}>
        <button (click)="actionOne(user)" mat-menu-item> one </button>
        <button (click)="actionTwo(user)" mat-menu-item> two </button>
    </mat-menu>
</div>
```

but I know that #menu{{user}} is not valid syntax and am not sure what would be passed to [matMenuTriggerFor] so I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you do not have to worry about dynamic hash reference for mat-menus, just do it like that and ***ngFor** will do it on it's own

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
    <mat-chip [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"> click {{ user }} menu </mat-chip>
    <mat-menu #menu>
        <button (click)="actionOne(user)" mat-menu-item> one </button>
        <button (click)="actionTwo(user)" mat-menu-item> two </button>
    </mat-menu>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't even think to try this, thank you.